# How can i restrict template directory in url in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using wordpress for my site. Here  2 type of urls for same page.
EX: `http://www.chitramala.in/news/`

This is original category url,

when i add adding template directory to this url . then also it is working
Ex:

```
http://www.chitramala.in/wp-content/themes/chitramala2014/news/
```

I want to work only first url. 2nd one is wrong url. How to solve this issue. Please help me

Comment: already available in public directory

Comment: Please check bellow answer..

Comment: Did you changed anything in the default Wordpress htaccess ? This is not the normal behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Make .htaccess file in public directory.
Add following code

```
    Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
rewriterule ^wp-content/themes/chitramala2014/news/(.*)$ http://www.chitramala.in/news/$1 [r=301,nc]
```

Comment: Add all urls like this